# Display author bio box

Tags: posts, functions

I have post page with author info. But it seems author bio box should only display if content has been entered. How to check it?

```
<?php if(get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )) != 0){
    echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) , 80);
}?>
<div class="post-full-desc">
    <h6><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></h6>
    <p><?php echo get_the_author_meta('description')?></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if( !empty(get_the_author_meta('description')) ){
       echo get_the_author_meta('description');
    }
```

You can use empty() function to check the content entered or not.